# Code no longer displays, despite being selectable

Tags: bug, markdown, code-formatting

Since today, suddenly code no longer displays for me:

[image: Screenshot showing empty code blocks]

The same happens for in-line code, also that in comments. However, I can select the code:

[image]

and copy-paste it to a text editor. Is this a new bug?

I'm running Windows 11 with Firefox 103.0.2 (64-bit) with [uBlock Origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UBlock_Origin), Adblock Ultimate, [Privacy Badger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy_Badger) and [Tampermonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tampermonkey).

Opening the same page in a fresh, incognito browser window without add-ins does indeed display the code. Could this be related to [the earlier issue today](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381510/325771) and be fixed by simply waiting for caching to catch up?

Comment: No repro with Chrome, try clearing cache, removing extensions, etc.

Comment: No repro on FireFox 103.0.2 (64-bit) on macos 12.5 either.

Comment: Regarding cache, in Chrome you can force it to clear in several ways: 1) Reload with CTRL+F5, 2) Open dev console, go to Network tab, tick "Disable cache" checkbox and reload, and 3) Clearing all cache from Settings. Pretty sure Firefox also have at least part of those.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard jup, clearing cache through settings did the trick. CTRL-F5 did not btb.

Comment: Worth self answer then, IMO.

Comment: Heh, just thought of something, the broken JS yesterday was an earthquake, and this one here is an [aftershock](https://earthquake.usgs.gov/learn/glossary/?term=aftershocks). ;-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript is broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381510/javascript-is-broken)

Comment: Wrong close reason, no changes were made to the system. Proper action would be marking it as [tag:status-norepro] as the bug already fixed, and it's something local for some users with aggressive caching.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard the dupe would fit though, as the answer there answers this question as well (at least, that's what I think. A dev would need to confirm that)

Comment: The dupe explains why it was broken in the first place, but doesn't mention you have to clear cache.

Comment: For future reference regarding refreshes, a hard reload in Chrome (`Ctrl + F5` or `Ctrl + Shift + R`) makes a fresh request for the page without cached data, but doesn't necessarily dump any other cache for the page. "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" in Chrome _does_, however, which can be accessed by opening dev tools and then [right clicking the refresh button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6KIy.png). [A more thorough explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14969509).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out the problem was broken JS stored in the browser's local cache. This issue was possibly related to [this quick-fix earlier today](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381510/325771).

These are the steps I took to clear the cache (Firefox):

1. Go to *Settings*
2. *Privacy & Security*
3. *Cookies and Site Data*
4. *Clear Data*
5. *Cached Web Content*

Note, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> didn't help unfortunately.